# Fail to access file on server

Tags: javascript, ajax

Sorry for this basic question am a bit confused now.

I am learning javascript and mounted a page on the [00webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/)  site to play around and do all the tests.  So far it works fine but am stuck following this tutorial [AJAX](http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson18.php)

I created a txt file and uploaded to the server; have tried copying it on the same path as the javascript, giving full path, at the public root, all I get is the 404 server response.

I noticed that browsing to that file on my navigator(chrome), send a message saying "Failed to open".
I guess this is a problem with accessing the resource on the server, if that is so... am not sure how to configure it. Giving it the 777 file permission didn't make any difference.

This is done in a shared server on a free hosting service, do you think I have restrictions configuring this?

From the index.html I use this button with id "btnAjax" to later bind the event on the javascript file

```
...
<div id="ajax">
 <input type="button" id="btnAjax" value="Testing AJAX" onclick="getText('ajaxretrieve.txt')"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdir/ajax.js">

</script>
....
```

As for the javascript (ajax.js) here is how the button is bound to the server response
    var myRequest;

```
function getText(url)
{

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
     myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

}
else
{
       myRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


myRequest.open("GET", url, true);
myRequest.send(null); // nothing to send
myRequest.onreadystatechange = getData;

}

// handles the server response
function getData()
{
    var myBtn = document.getElementById("btnAjax");

if(myRequest.readyState === 4)
{
        alert(myRequest.status);
        if(myRequest.status === 200)
    {

          var text = myRequest.responseText;

          myBtn.nodeValue = text;
    }
}
}
```

From the code above I can get the alert on the browser, am printing there the status with the value of 404. I couldn't never get the success status of 200.

Comment: Can you share the link to your test site? Also I think the URL should include the `jsdir/` in the path.

Comment: I tried like this also getText('http://selflearning.net84.net/data/ajaxretrieve.txt'), which is the full URL I get same problem. Probably you will notice the error I get when trying to save the link.

Comment: As I already mentioned, I have placed  the txt file on several locations without luck; on the subfolder data, same path as the script, at the public root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.txt files are restricted in 000webhost for security reasons.

Source: http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-design-html/18175-cannot-read-text-any-text-files.html

Try renaming to `html` or `htm` and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah I suspected that if you read my post. This was so suspicious. Thank you!

Comment: So how is a txt file a security problem on my very limited free service... let me read the whole thread, but would be good to hear your explanation.

Comment: Free hosts are extremely vulnerable to spam, hacking and illegal activities. We have no way of knowing exactly what tools, techniques and systems they use to prevent misuse of their hosting, but it's very possible txt files could interfere with some settings or have been used in the past to misuse the TOS of the site.